# Custom authorization

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization

I'm trying to implement custom authorization without having much of success.  I've created an overload for `OnAuthorize` in my base controller which does the authorization. But it do not seem to work correctly together with windows authentication (I get a login prompt in IE when my authorization checks have passed)

Another approach that I've read about is to create a custom requires attribute which does the authentication. That seems more like a hack than a proper solution (or are there no extension points in asp/mvc which can be used for this?)

Can someone show me how to do custom authorization that works with the standard RequiresAttribute?

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC3 RC.

Comment: It would help if you could show what your `OnAuthorize` method does and provide details about how your auth is configured in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing concepts.

There's the concept of the authentication method that your application uses. This is handled by ASP.NET itself and you need to configure this in web.config. By default MVC projects templates use forms authentication.

The other concept is how your application behaves for authorized (or unauthorized) users in different roles etc. That's where `OnAuthorize`, `IAuthorizationFilter` and things like `AuthorizeAttribute` fit. For example you can only allow access to a part of your application to users in the 'Admin' role.

Comment: Nope, I'm not confusing the concepts. I'm trying to implement custom authorization using my own authorization store. Windows is used as authentication method.